# app crashing while fetching sms from inbox in version 5.0. Crashing in onViewCreated() Method

Tags: android, sms

Please find code for k. This is inside a fragment. Please help. Its only crashing in android `version 5.0`. If you want i can also share play store console details.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle(getString(R.string.dnd_caps));
//  getListView().addHeaderView(mHeader);
    if (((DNDMasterActivityNEW) getActivity()).checkPermissions()) {
        dialogWait = new DialogWait(getActivity());
        dialogWait.setCancelable(false);
        dialogWait.show();
        try {
            SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            List<SubscriptionInfo> subscriptionInfoList = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
            for (SubscriptionInfo subscriptionInfo : subscriptionInfoList) {
                int subscriptionId = subscriptionInfo.getSubscriptionId();
                int simSlotIndex = subscriptionInfo.getSimSlotIndex();
                String simNumber = subscriptionInfo.getNumber();
                String carrierName = subscriptionInfo.getCarrierName().toString();
                String displayName = subscriptionInfo.getDisplayName().toString();
                Log.d("DND_SUBS", "subscriptionId:" + subscriptionId);
                Log.d("DND_SUBS", "simslotIndex:" + simSlotIndex);
                Log.d("DND_SUBS", "simNumber:" + simNumber);
                Log.d("DND_SUBS", "carrierName:" + carrierName);
                Log.d("DND_SUBS", "displayName:" + displayName);
                hm.put(subscriptionId, simSlotIndex);
            }
        } catch (NoClassDefFoundError | Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getApplicationContext());
        Boolean isAppRegistered = settings.getBoolean(Global.isAppRegistered, false);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmResults<trai.gov.in.dnd.ml.model.Sms> smses = getAllSms();
        ArrayList<trai.gov.in.dnd.ml.model.Sms> smsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        smsArrayList.addAll(realm.copyFromRealm(smses));
     //   AsyncTaskRunner asyncTaskRunner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
     //   asyncTaskRunner.execute();
        dialogWait.dismiss();
        if (!smsArrayList.isEmpty()) {
            adapter = new SmsListAdapterRecyclerView(getActivity(), smsArrayList);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
            recyclerView.setLayoutFrozen(false);
            recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(30);
            recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            recyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            ll_probable_spam.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            no_sms.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

I just wanted to know does this line can also crash

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
```

or why the app is crashing

Please find attached stack trace

```
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
  at trai.gov.in.dnd.app.SmsFragment.onViewCreated (SmsFragment.java:97)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1314)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState (FragmentManager.java:1528)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1595)
  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps (BackStackRecord.java:758)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps (FragmentManager.java:2363)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether (FragmentManager.java:2149)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps (FragmentManager.java:2103)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions (FragmentManager.java:2013)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run (FragmentManager.java:710)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5233)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:898)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace of crash . How are you expecting and answer without stacktrace .

Comment: Please find it. I have edited

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` i.e this method is introduced after `LOLLIPOP_MR1` not on `LOLLIPOP_MR1`. Well its just a guess.

Comment: Please let me know how can i correct this in my build

Comment: what is on `SmsFragment.java:97`?

Comment: this line      SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `SubscriptionManager`

```
SubscriptionManager sm=SubscriptionManager.from(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

> Call requires API level 22 (current min is 19): android.telephony.SubscriptionManager)

You have to check for Build version before calling. Below is an example modify it as per your need .

```
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
public static String getSubscriptionInfo(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
        return "Not supported";
    if (!((DNDMasterActivityNEW) getActivity()).checkPermissions())
        return "No permission";
    StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
    SubscriptionManager sm = SubscriptionManager.from(context);
    // Do your task here
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

**NOTE:-** Do not add `@TargetApi` annotation in `onViewCreated()` its useless. `onViewCreated()` is fragment's life cycle method it is meant to get called .
 
**Edit**
 You can first check for availabilty and then proceed further . As

```
 private boolean canGetSubscriptionInfo{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
        return false;
    if (!((DNDMasterActivityNEW) getActivity()).checkPermissions())
        return false;
   return true;
}
```

Comment: How should i use this in my code because you have written a  function. should i call the function by replacing it with line   SubscriptionManager sm=SubscriptionManager.from(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what you have to do . for reference see the updated answer .

Comment: Thanks I WILL TRY AND LET YOU KNOW THE RESULT

Comment: It actually stops crash.. but it cannot fetch sms from inbox. Is there any way out to fetch sms

Comment: I cannot upvote. But it definitely helped in removing crash

Comment: I haven't had chance to work with Telephony yet . You have to do some research on this . Read about `TelephonyManager` and its helper classes maybe this will fulfill your requirements. Thx

Answer (score 1):

The solution is here

Subscription class is not available below 6.0 , therefore app crashed. I removed that for version 5.0 and 5.1 and it worked fine. Thanks